# How to run the following command on 3 different regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, groovy

I wrote the following Groovy code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/groovy
def p = ['/usr/local/bin/aws', 'ec2', 'describe-vpcs'].execute() | 'grep -w CidrBlock'.execute() | ['awk', '{print $2}'].execute() | ['tr', '-d', '"\\"\\|,\\|\\{\\|\\\\["'].execute() | 'uniq'.execute()
p.waitFor()
def output = []
p.text.eachLine { line ->
        output << line
}

output.each {
        println it
}
```

The output looks like so:

```
172.31.0.0/16
172.60.0.0/16
172.54.0.0/16
172.59.0.0/16
```

The output of this code is being added to an Extended Parameter in Jenkins and displays a list of CIDR blocks in use.

Currently, the command only returns output for the default region which is us-west-2.

I would like to run this code and collect all CIDR blocks in use from all regions (in my case it's Oregon [us-west-2], Ireland [eu-west-1] and Virginia [us-east-1]).

How can it be done?

Comment: Do you mean beyond running awscli with the --region xyz option?

Comment: Yea, I need to join the results of the command after running it on all 3 regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all available regions:

```
def regions = ['/usr/local/bin/aws', 'ec2', 'describe-regions', '--output', 'text'].execute() | 'cut -f3'.execute()
        regions.waitFor()
        def output = []
        regions.text.eachLine { region ->
            def p = ['/usr/local/bin/aws', 'ec2', 'describe-vpcs', '--region', region].execute() | 'grep -w CidrBlock'.execute() | ['awk', '{print $2}'].execute() | ['tr', '-d', '"\\"\\|,\\|\\{\\|\\\\["'].execute() | 'uniq'.execute()
            p.waitFor()
            p.text.eachLine { line ->
                output << line
            }
        }
        output.each {
            println it
        }
```